# How do you Fetch a nested JSON key value then assign to variable?

Tags: json, fetch

I'm not able to pick out a certain key/value from a fetched JSON file, and then assign it to a variable.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
var url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/'
fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((hmm) => console.log(hmm.results))
```

The above code serves to return info from the top branch, "results", but I can't get any deeper.

Modifying it to `.then((hmm) => console.log(hmm.results.gender))` returns undefined.

I'd then like to assign the Value from the "gender" Key to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is an array.

You need to do `results[0].gender`

`.then((hmm) => console.log(hmm.results[0].gender))`

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
var url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/'
fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(function (hmm) {
    var data = hmm.results[0].gender;
    console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: thanks Nafis, this worked great, and I was able to apply it to the actual API I'm working with..